# Tartaglia cubic roots problem

Tags: polynomials

$x=\sqrt[3]{q+\sqrt{q^2-p^3}}-\sqrt[3]{-q+\sqrt{q^2-p^3}}$

Why is it that this must be true $q^2-p^3<0$ for x to have 3 distinct real roots?

Comment: Do you mean $q^2−p^3<0$? Square roots are always positive.

Comment: Yes, sorry- will adjust.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the [casus irreducibilis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_irreducibilis) of the cubic. You *need* to use complex numbers even if the roots are all real. The proof needs Galois theory.

Comment: Thank you. Before I try to delve into it, is learning Galois theory quickly feasible?

Comment: @Alyosha, not really, sorry.

Comment: Oh well. I'll return to this problem in a year or so.

Comment: @Alyosha, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/152818/what-is-the-prerequisite-knowledge-for-learning-galois-theory

Comment: Sorry to whip a dead post, but where I'm reading it says that you can prove this by 'considering the nature of stationary points'. Is this correct?

Comment: @Alyosha, it may be. My point is that proving that you cannot solve a cubic with three real roots using radicals without using complex numbers needs Galois theory. Not that if $q^2-p^3<0$ then it has three real roots. I seems that I did not really answer your question. I suggest you add an answer yourself.