# Polynomials of the form $X^n-c$

Tags: polynomials, soft-question, terminology, cyclotomic-polynomials

Is there any specific name for the polynomials of the form $X^n-c$ for some $n$ and $c$ is a complex number? They seem to be closely related to Cyclotomic polynomials.

Comment: $X^n-c\,$ is just $\,c\left(Y^n - 1\right)\,$ with the substitution $\,Y = c^{-1/n}X\,$, which is indeed the product of $\,Y-1\,$ and one or more cyclotomic polynomials. I don't know of a special name for $\,Y^n - 1\,$.

Comment: Thanks, the reason I am asking is because of the following statement:

"This generalizes: the roots of any rational polynomial are expressible in radicals if and only if its corresponding splitting field sits inside of a subfield obtained by taking splitting fields of polynomials of the form  $X^n-c$" in this Quora:

https://www.quora.com/How-does-Galois-theory-relate-to-the-solvability-of-polynomial-equations

It looks like its an important polynomial to determine when the roots are expressible in radicals. I am searching hard to find a proof. Any ideas?
 .

Comment: See [Solvable groups and solution by radicals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_theory#Solvable_groups_and_solution_by_radicals) and [What is the prerequisite knowledge for learning Galois theory?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/152818/what-is-the-prerequisite-knowledge-for-learning-galois-theory)

Comment: Yes, I get these. I feel the proof of this would make someone intuitively understand the unsolvability of the quintic using radicals. I am looking for proof of this statement, specifically. I was able to prove one way. The other way is a bit elusive.

Comment: There should be a name, because then one could better explain Abel/Ruffini and Galois theory to interested laymen (the statement I mean, not the proofs). Maybe call them "radical polynomials". A makeshift solution is "polynomials without mixed terms".

Comment: Yes, precisely. These seem to be very important polynomials to explain GT to novices. I wonder if the Galois groups for these polynomials are normal and solvable. I read that the Galois group for the cyclotomic polynomials is abelian so these could be abelian. But I am wondering if they are normal.

Comment: @user2167741 The extra ingredient (beyond cyclotomic fields) that you are looking for to solve this question is called [Kummer theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kummer_theory).